# Updating one value in an object of arrays

Tags: reactjs

I have an array containing objects with details for an image (URL, description, likes) I'm trying to clone an Instagram page, and update the "likes" for that 1 image on click.

Attempted to map through the array and return with the "likes" + 1.

Here are 3 separate files starting with the data. The data is stored in the "Main" section in the state Gallery. So to overview, I want to increase the number of likes when I click on that image. But when I setState, I have no idea how I can only target one value in one object of the array. I would rather just update the state rather than create a new state onClick and then change the value that was! I'm looking for the best practice. (as this is the only way I can learn) Thanks in advance.

```
const images =[
{
    url:'./images/img1.jpg',
    description:"test1",
    likes:0,
    index:0
},
{
    url:'./images/img2.jpg',
    description:"test1",
    likes:3,
    index:1
},
{
    url:'./images/img3.jpg',
    description:"test1",
    likes:4,
    index:2
},
{
    url:'./images/img2.jpg',
    description:"test1"
},
{
    url:'./images/img2.jpg',
    description:"test1"
},
{
    url:'./images/img2.jpg',
    description:"test1"
},

]

export default images


import React from 'react'

const Gallery =(props)=>{
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="main-gallery">

                {props.gallery.map((item,index) => (
                    <div key={index} className='img-container' onClick= {props.increaseLikes}>
                        <img className='gallery-images' src={item.url}/> 
                        <p className='likes'>likes {item.likes}</p>
                    </div>
                 ))}

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Gallery


import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Nav from './Components/Navbar/Nav'
import Header from './Components/Header/Header'
import Carousel from './Components/Carousel/Carousel'
import Data from './Data'
import Gallery from './Components/Gallery/Gallery'

class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state={
            post:100,
            gallery:[],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){

        this.setState({
            gallery:Data
        })

    }

    increaseLikes=()=>{

        //no idea how to update

    }

    render() {

       return (
           <div>
               <Gallery gallery={this.state.gallery} increaseLikes= {this.increaseLikes}/>
           </div>
       )

    }

}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your increaseLikes function needs to get id of the image from the Gallery component.

So the code must be like something like this:
I assumed your data has an unique id property.

```js
increaseLikes = id => {

    const updatedData = this.state.gallery.map(image => {
      if (image.id === id) {
        return { ...image, likes: image.likes ? image.likes + 1 : 1 };
      } else {
        return image;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      gallery: updatedData
    })
  };
```

Gallery component code:

```
import React from "react";

const Gallery = props => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="main-gallery">
        {props.gallery.map((item, index) => (
          <div
            key={item.id}
            className="img-container"
            onClick={() => props.increaseLikes(item.id)}
          >
            <img
              className="gallery-images"
              src={item.url}
              alt={item.description}
            />
            <p className="likes">likes  {item.likes ? item.likes : 0} </p>
            <hr />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Gallery;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help that now makes sense

Comment: @Lee I am sorry that you changed the answer:(  Your new accepted answer only suggested using url as unique value. But in the sample data,  url was not unique.

Comment: apolgoies, I wanted your answer. As much as the other helped, you're correct in what you've just stated. I beleive thats now been changed

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `url` (That seems to be the only unique value) of the images in order to update your array, I've made a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mjv9pf) where you can see how to do it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you this all makes sense :)

Comment: in the sample data,  url was not unique, so I added an unique Id property. In real life projects using an Id should be preferred .

Comment: Yeah, I've edited the `images` array in order to make a value unique, it's not you could not do this.

Comment: @SuleymanSah, why did you delete your answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347756/how-to-return-current-user-information-from-mongodb-in-a-mevn-stack-app

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 because I thought I couldn't understand your question

Comment: @SuleymanSah, that answer might have worked, could we try again? What should I clarify?

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 lets talk in your question