# How to return current user information from MongoDB in a MEVN stack app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js

I am attempting to build a basic login/registration app using Vue, Express, Node, and MongoDB. I have been successful in setting up the Express router to enable registration and logging in of users, with basic user info stored in MongoDB. I am attempting to return user data back to the screen after logging in. So far, I have set up `router.get()` in Express to return the username of all users back to the screen. However, I want to configure the `axios.get()` method in Vue.js to return only the username of the logged in user, as opposed to all the user names stored in MongoDB. Normally in Firebase I would use something like `let snapshot = await ref.where('userid', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()` to send back info exclusively about the current user. How can I set up my `axios.get()` method to execute something similar? My code is below:

logged in page

```
<template>
  <b-row>
    <b-col cols="12">
      <h2>
        You are now logged in!
        <b-link @click="logout()">(Logout)</b-link>
      </h2>
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>User Names</th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user._id">
          <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <ul v-if="errors && errors.length">
        <li v-for="error of errors" :key="error._id">
          <b-alert show>{{error.message}}</b-alert>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'BookList',
  data () {
    return {
      users: [],
      errors: []
    }
  },
  created () {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/auth`)
      .then(response => {
        this.users = response.data
      })
    },
    methods: {
      logout () {
        localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken')
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'Login'
        })
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

GET route in Express

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  User.find(function (err, products) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(products);
  });
});
```

User.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
  password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var user = this;
    if (this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                user.password = hash;
                next();
            });
        });
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (passw, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(passw, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Register route

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
    res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please pass username and password.'});
  } else {
    var newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password
    });
    // save the user
    newUser.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Username already exists.'});
      }
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.'});
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: @SuleymanSah, why did you delete your answer?

Comment: Is your problem in get route?

Comment: I think the problem is in both the route AND the axios.get() method in the Vue.js template. I am logging in as a specific user and want to configure both the route and the get method to return only my user name to the screen.

Comment: I dont have experience with vue, but I can help in express side, I undeleted the answer, check if it helps

Comment: Did the route worked with the code in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your user model has username and password fields, and your password is encrypted in db.

For finding user with username, if user found comparing the user.password with the encrypted password in the request body.
If user not found, or passwords don't match, I send `400-Bad Request`.

```js
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  if (!(username && password))
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "username and password are required" });

  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({ username });
    if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ error: "invalid login" });

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!validPassword) return res.status(400).json({ error: "invalid login" });

    user.password = undefined;

    res.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

To hash the password before saving the user, can you add this code to the user model?

```js
UserSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);
    next();
});
```

Register route:

```js
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  if (!username || !password)
    return res.json({ success: false, msg: "Please pass username and password." });

  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({ username });

    if (user) return res.json({ success: false, msg: "Username already exists." });

    user = new User({ username, password });

    await user.save();

    res.json({ success: true, msg: "Successful created new user." });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.json({ success: false, msg: "Something went bad" });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks again. This seems like a logical answer, but it is still not returning the specific user. I used console.log in the created life cycle hook, but no data is being returned to this.users. I think the Vue.js function is fine. Is there perhaps another configuration of the get route that could be used?

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 this route must return the user, if the user model has username and password fields, and the password is not kept encrypted in db. Can you try route with postman?

Comment: Good call. I just tried running the get route in postman. It returns the 2nd error, "username and password are required"

Comment: @actually this must be a post request, I edit answer

Comment: i should note, the password is encrypted with ```bcrypt-nodejs```.

Comment: Ok, I edited answer, but I am not near to my computer, you should compare the user.password with decryted req.body.password, if not equal return res.status(400).json({error: “username or password incorrect})

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 I edited answer, can you try post request with postman?

Comment: Dont forget to const bcrypt = require(“bcryptjs”);

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18  bcrypt-nodejs  is deprecated, please use bcryptjs

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the feedback . I tried implementing your code, as well as updating the bcrypt dependency to bcryptjs. Updating to this new dependency appears to prevent the registration component from pushing the encrypted password into MongoDB. This this issue might also be preventing the password from being compared in your code above, since there is no password stored in MongoDB to compare. So I think I am going to need to update the Mongoose-based user module with the new bcryptjs dependency as well.

Comment: User.js is mainly for rendering the input in Schema, but it is also used to facilitate the encryption of the password. I took a look at the documentation for bcryptjs, and am not really sure what the difference is between bcryptjs and bcrypt-nodejs in regards to the setup of genSalt and Hash. Any idea how to modify User.js to reflect the newly install bcryptjs dependency? I think resolving this will issue might fix the whole problem.

Comment: In other words, I am getting the invalid login error from your code, probably because there is no password stored in MongoDB after installing bcryptjs. bcryptjs setup will likely need to be resolved first.

Comment: See User.js. I added it above.

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18  you also need to use bcryptjs in your register route to hash the plain password. If you register a user with this, then you will be able to login.

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 I saw, it looks good, can you register a user with this code, and try to login?

Comment: How do reconfigure the register route to hash? See register route above.

Comment: Can you use this simple code instead of yours for UserSchema.pre ..


UserSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);
    next();
});

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200757/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-js-is-awesome18).

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 I have some suggestions in chat, are you getting notifications?

Comment: Hi SuleymanSah. I am still running into some issues with this component. See the chat. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200851/discussion-between-js-is-awesome18-and-suleymansah).